# Is the Logitech Unifying Receiver compatible with all Logitech peripherals?

Tags: logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver, logitech-keyboard

I own multiple Logitech devices, and each one of them seem to have their own receiver, occupying USB ports.

I read up on *Logitech Unifying Receiver*, and it seems to be able to connect multiple Logitech wireless devices.

However, if I just buy this one receiver, will I be able to connect my *existing* wireless devices? Or will I be forced to buy new keyboard and mouse in order to use the unifying receiver?

I'd rather not spend money on something I cannot use.

The devices are:

#### PC 1

- Logitech Dinovo Edge keyboard
- Logitech MX Air mouse

#### PC 2

- Logitech Dinovo Keyboard
- Logitech VX mouse

Comment: I thought that you get the receiver with devices that support it, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unifying receiver only works on newer products that support that receiver. For those one receiver can be used to connect multiple devices to your system. I do have 5 logitech mice and only 1 is the newer unifying receiver type - that receiver definitely does not pair with the four Nano VXs I have.

Comment: I have several of the unifying devices but only one has more than one device attached.  The best part of these devices, IMO, is that they can be replaced separately - you can purchase only the dongle should it fail or be broken.  In the past you had to replace the entire set (both dongle and mouse) should one fail.  Additionally, the micro-dongle size makes it much less likely to be broken.  I have used Logitech for years because they have the best products and offer excellent warranties.

Comment: It's easy to recognize Unifying devices: they have the Unifying logo on their bottom side.  It's the logo that's also on the receiver: a red square with black sun icon.

Answer (score 5):

There's a rather long but useful list of Logitech products, that includes the ones that do support Unifying receiver technology here:

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_Logitech_products

Unfortunately Logitech does not seem to have a similar list so thanks goes to Wikiwand, and their contributors.